# How to make Java string assert true

Tags: java

I need to find some code which will replace the [???] to make the assertion true. However I have been stuck on this for hours. Does anyone have an idea?

```
`public class Exercise{
     public static void main(String [] arg){
         int foo=10; 
         assert ("Foo".equals("Bar[???]")):"assertionFoo=Bar?"; 
    }
}`
```

Comment: what do you want to assert in terms of literal?

Comment: Show us the original question, without context the answer is "you don't".

Comment: Original Question: The original question was to find some code that made the assert statement true. It does say "the answer is not required to have balanced parentheses inside string literals"

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `"Foo"` is not equal to `"Bar[???]"` no matter what value you use to replace `[???]`.

Comment: That int is so random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Exercise{
 public static void main(String [] args){
     int foo=10; 
     assert ("Foo".equals("Bar".replace("Bar","Foo")):"assertionFoo=Bar?"; 
 }
}
```